# How do I enable 32 bit support for a binary compiled CGI script?

Tags: linux, apache, centos6

I am running CentOS 6 on my webserver with linux and apache. in the command line when I type in:

```
# readelf -h $(which init) | grep "Class"
```

It returns:

```
Class:                             ELF64
```

How do I enable 32 bit support for a binary compiled CGI script? I assume this is the problem right?

Answer (score 1):

found out that I was trying to execute an old 32 bit compiled binary script on a server that does not support 32 bit. I had to run

```
yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

then i restarted apache for safe measure and viola! I know this will only work on CentOS, I think the command for another system is:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

so try these if you are having the same problem

Comment: Correct. Info came from htmlos.org most likely... I posted that there years ago.. :)